# How do I find which jQuery event is being called when I click a textbox?

Tags: jquery, html, events, dom

I've inherited a piece of software and in it is a form where I cannot figure out where the click event is in jQuery.

When the user clicks in a textbox on the form, the checkbox next to it toggles using a jquery call that I cannot seem to find. I've searched the associates .js files and for the life of me I cannot find it.

Are there any tools, tips or tricks I can use to find what is being called to trigger the click event, so that I can alter/deactivate it?

Below is a sample of the markup around the form:

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_other1" id="checkbox_other1" value="checkbox_other1" />
    <label for="checkbox_other1">Other <input type="text" id="textfield_other1" name="textfield_other1" size="35" maxlength="35">.</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_other2" id="checkbox_other2" value="checkbox_other2" />
    <label for="checkbox_other2">Other <label for="checkbox_other2">
        <input type="text" id="textfield_other2" name="textfield_other2" size="35" maxlength="35">.
    </label>
</li>
```

Thanks.

**SOLUTION**
So it seems I was thinking too high level. It wasn't jquery/javascript that was causing the issue, but it was the label tags that was attaching the textfield to the checkbox. Thanks for all the assistance.

Comment: Couldn't you provide link to your website?

Comment: Seems you're having another person's code. Programmatically there is no way to find out which other method triggered your second input's click event. Your best bet probably is to use text search for `.click()` or `.trigger('click')` eventually substituting the single quote with a double quote.

Comment: Sorry, can't provide a link. It's on a dev server that can't be accessed without credentials.

Comment: I searched for click and toggle, and neither has shown a suitable piece of code that could be responsible.

Comment: @JustJon is it a specific element which makes the toggle occur, or all text boxes?

Comment: There are two textboxes and each is specific to the textbox next to it.

Comment: Try running the page with Javascript disabled.  If the form/field isn't there then it was probably added with Javascript (which will make finding references to it a *little* bit more difficult).  If it **is** still there, then it was in the original markup and JQuery must be using some sort of selector to find it.  Does the field have any ID, class, or parent with ID or class?

Comment: Also, can you provide any portion or abstract of *any* of the script or markup?  Every little bit helps!

Comment: The form and field are not dynamically generated. I tried searching the .js files for the id/name but nothing appeared. HTML code in next comment due to size limitation.

Comment: <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_other1" id="checkbox_other1" value="checkbox_other1" />
<label for="checkbox_other1">Other
    <input type="text" id="textfield_other1" name="textfield_other1" size="35" maxlength="35">.</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_other2" id="checkbox_other2" value="checkbox_other2" />
    <label for="checkbox_other2">Other
    <label for="checkbox_other2">
         <input type="text" id="textfield_other2" name="textfield_other2" size="35" maxlength="35">.</label></li>

Comment: Alright, so just about everything has an insane amount of attribute data on it. Fortunately, name, id, and value are the same in almost all cases.  Have you tried searching the JS for specific tag names?  Perhaps the action is applied to all checkboxes (regardless of ID or name).  Perhaps only when they're next to a field?  (Also, I took the liberty of including your markup in the original question.  Hope you don't mind.)

Comment: Try using some other online tools that help pinpoint these things, for example [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event).

Comment: Kilanash has an excellent point.  Many browsers (Webkit, and Firefox especially) have awesome Javascript debug tools.

Comment: I have tried with Chrome's Developer tools, Firebug on Firefox and Visual Event. All to no avail.

@SandyGifford Thanks for the markup. I did a grep on the entire directory. There's no reference to the text boxes at all, and the word toggle is used only once. It's vexing.

Comment: Even if you found the problem wasn't what you thought it was originally, you should still pick the answer that you felt best covered your question for any future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 4):

[Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event) is very handy tool to find events on webpage.

You can bookmark it and then use on any webpage.

Also available as [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why this took me so long to realize, but you can print the onclick handler directly:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function thisiswhyimhot()
            {
                alert("this is why you're not");
            }

            function mybodyisready()
            {
                alert(document.getElementById("hottestdivever").onclick);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="mybodyisready()">
        <div id="hottestdivever" onclick="thisiswhyimhot()"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Will Pop up an alert with the following:

```
function onclick(event) {
thisiswhyimhot()
}
```

If the handler was set with JQuery it's stored in a slightly different fashion:

```
alert(jQuery._data(document.getElementById("hottestdivever"), "events").click[0].handler);
```

That will give you something to search for in your JS.

And finally, a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PacmanBits/a88uL/) demoing both the vanilla Javascript and jQuery methods.

In other news, I have a new function name for every body onload I write from now **until the end of time**...

Answer (score -2):

try event.type

```
$("#test").on("click change", function(event){
    alert(event.type + " is fired");
});
```

Comment: I don't think OP is looking for that

Comment: -1: You just read the title and ignored the question, didn't you?

Comment: Thanks. I know how to trigger an event, but I can't seem to figure out which/where the event is being fired.

Comment: try event.target. In jQuery event.target always refers to the element that triggered the event.

Comment: I know the element that triggered the event, I'm trying to find the handler that is causing the checkboxes to toggle.